# probability that 3 out of sample of 10 are female

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

A professor randomly selects three new teaching assistants from a total of 10 applicants: 6 male and 4 female students. The probability that no females are hired is?.

Is it biased probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just select one male student after another male student.

Probability of "First male student is selected" is 6/10

Probability of "Second male student is selected" is 5/9, because one male student has been selected already.

You go on like this and multiply the particular probabilities.

greeting,

calculus.

Comment: thanks its easy to understand now!

Comment: That´s fine. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The probability is $$\frac{\binom{6}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}}$$

Comment: I figured I would note that this is a Hypergeometric Distribution. It's a very nice tool to have for discrete probability questions. :-)